# How to express a disjunction of inequalities compactly without redundant answers/solutions

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

Consider what I have tried:

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C) :-
   (  dif(A, B)
   ;  dif(A, C)
   ).
```

While this definition is fine from a declarative viewpoint it contains many redundancies. Think of:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 2.
   A = 1, B = 2, C = 2
;  A = 1, B = 2, C = 2.   % unexpected redundant solution
```

And not even in this case:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
   A = 1, B = 2, C = 3
;  A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.   % unexpected redundant solution
```

At least, here is a case without redundancy...

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 1.
   A = 1, B = 2, C = 1
;  false.                 % unexpected inefficient leftover choicepoint
```

...but with a resource-wasting leftover choicepoint.

Rare are the occasions where this definition is efficient:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 1, C = 2.
   A = 1, B = 1, C = 2.
```

Also that the most general query produces two answers sounds very inefficient to me:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C).
   dif:dif(A,B)
;  dif:dif(A,C).
```

... which produces also the following redundancy:

```
?- dif_to_orto(1, B, B).
   dif:dif(1,B)
;  dif:dif(1,B).    % unexpected redundant answer
```

One `dif/2` would be enough!

Is there a way to avoid all these redundancies and inefficiencies?

Comment: aren't the duplicate solutions due to B being equal to C? what about having dif(B,C) in the second case?

Comment: @coredump: Added two cases for clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about this one:

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C) :-
   dif(A-A, B-C).
```

The test cases:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 2.
A = 1,
B = C, C = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 1.
A = C, C = 1,
B = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 1, C = 2.
A = B, B = 1,
C = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C).
dif(f(B, A), f(A, C)).

?- dif_to_orto(1, B, B).
dif(B, 1).
```

Comment: @false I'm puzzled. Did I do anything wrong? Should I retreat this answer?

Comment: No, looks like a perfect answer

Comment: `dif_to_orto(1, B, B).` is another nice case

Comment: In SICStus, the two last calls give different results: `prolog:dif(A-A,B-C)` and `prolog:dif(1-1,B-B)` respectively. So the `dif/2` goal is not "simplified". I think the behavior is ultimately the same, but I thought it was worth noting it...

Comment: @jnmonette: SICStus shows the original goal which is at least in the first case much more intuitive than what you get in SWI with its out-of-nowhere structure `f/2`. In the second case, SWI is in fact nicer.

Answer (score 8):

This solution first awaits for 2 of the 3 variables to be comparable, then if it cannot decide whether the constraint should succeed adds a new constraint:

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C) :-
    when((?=(A, B) ; ?=(A, C) ; ?=(B, C)),
         (   ?=(A, B) ->
              ( A\==B ->  true ; dif(A, C) )
         ;
             (
                ?=(A, C) ->
                 ( A\==C -> true ; dif(A, B) )
             ;
                 ( B\==C -> true ; dif(A, B) )
             )
         )).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 2.
A = 1,
B = C, C = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 1.
A = C, C = 1,
B = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C).
when((?=(A, C);?=(B, C);?=(A, B)),  (?=(A, B)->(A\==B->true;dif(A, C));?=(A, C)->(A\==C->true;dif(A, B));B\==C->true;dif(A, B))).

?- dif_to_orto(1, 2, Z).
true.

?- dif_to_orto(1, B, B).
dif(B, 1).
```

---

Reversing the checks:

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C) :-
    when((?=(A, B) ; ?=(A, C) ; ?=(B, C)),
         (
           A==B -> dif(A, C)
           ;
           ((A==C ; B==C) -> dif(A, B) ; true)
         )).
```

Comment: hehe, you mean to add the third comparison... will check it

Comment: @false: added the other branch.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one suggestion. As far as I can tell, it does not create choice points or redundant solutions:

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C) :-
   when(?=(A,B),(A==B->dif(A,C);true)),
   when(?=(A,C),(A==C->dif(A,B);true)).
```

For each disjunct, wait until it is known to be true or false. Once known, check its truth and, if false, then post the other disjunct.

Comment: `dif_to_orto(1, 2, Z).` gives `when(?=(1, Z),  (1==Z->dif(1, 2);true)).` How can I be sure that this is not tantamount to `false`?

Comment: BTW, if you have another solution, put it into another answer, so we can vote, accept and bounty them one-by-one.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the definition of [dif/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2):

```
dif_to_orto(A, B, C):-
   when((?=(A,B), ?=(A, C)), (A \== B -> true ; A \== C)).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 2.
A = 1,
B = C, C = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 3.
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C), A = 1, B = 2, C = 1.
A = C, C = 1,
B = 2.

?- dif_to_orto(A, B, C).
when((?=(A, B), ?=(A, C)),  (A\==B->true;A\==C)).
```

Comment: `dif_to_orto(1, 2, Z).` has some constraint attached to `Z`. Why? How can I be sure that it is irrelevant.

Comment: This answer delays the evaluation of the constraint until all three variables can be syntactically compared so in your example I only see that a manual inspection of the suspended goal determines it will succeed. Maybe delaying the evaluation until the three of them are comparable is not the best idea then...

Comment: Try another one.

Comment: BTW, syntax is here SWI-specific

Comment: @false: do you mean using `when/2` and `dif/2` ? I don't see them in GProlog. I don't have a license for Sicstus so I am not really familiar with their counterparts.

Comment: Just a missing pair of round brackets around the if-then-else.

Comment: Or, (in SWI), say `listing(dif_to_orto)`

Comment: I see it from the last sample run, the if-then-else prints surrounded with round brackets. Fixed code